# Whitelist PDF Embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

Is there a way or a service that allows for read-only (no saving or downloading) PDF embeds on one domain only? I know that there are services like Scribd and Slideshare but the problem is that while they do have private options, no service as far as I can tell allows to whitelist embeds (eg, only allow embeds on certain domains.) Vimeo can do this with videos and I don't mind paying for this service either. Any ideas?

I've also looked into PDFJS and it seems they have a NodeJS implementation so I was thinking maybe PDFJS could grab the PDF from the server on the server side and just stream it to the client without exposing the original PDF url. However I couldn't find good documentation for PDFJS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a PDF embed? Please clarify.

Comment: Just a method to embed a PDF document as inline content in a website. Like a YouTube or Vimeo embed.

Comment: So you are looking to simply frame a PDF into an HTML doc without the ability for the end user to download locally?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Slideshare and Scribd would work but they do not allow to limit the domains that embeds are allowed for documents so anyone could copy the embed code and embed it onto their own site.

Comment: The answer I posted below is for whitelisting, not for blocking the download... I think you could use something like PDFObject.js to prevent the download but from my understanding, once the PDF is served to the client, there is no way to prevent the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with any HTTP server, but since you mentioned Node in your question, we will solve the problem with that technology. I am assuming Express Framework as well.

First you simply host the PDF as a static file on your server. Then you would register some Middleware that detects a request for the PDF. If the hostname that is requesting does not match a list of "approved" domains, then you serve an error back to the client. If the domain is approved, you serve the PDF. This is no different then a .htaccess file in Apache that limits access by domain/IP or an "allow" block in a Nginx config. Here is a quick look at the Middleware function...

```
var approved = []; // Add your approved domains here.

// Make sure this middleware comes before app.use(express.static)
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url == '/path/to/PDF') {
        if(approved.indexOf(req.headers.host) {
            next();
        } else {
            next(new Error('Nu uh uh!')); 
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

This way even if they copy the embed code, they will get an error from the server (probably should be a 403, but those are semantics you can decide on yourself)